# $ \sin^2x_1+\dots \sin^2x_{10}=1$ implies $ 3(\sin x_1+\dots \sin x_{10})\leq \cos x_1 +\dots +\cos x_{10}. $

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, contest-math, radicals, tangent-line-method

> Suppose that $x_1,.\dots x_{10}\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and that
>   $$
> \sin^2x_1+\dots \sin^2x_{10}=1.
> $$
>   Prove that
>   $$
> 3(\sin x_1+\dots \sin x_{10})\leq \cos x_1 +\dots +\cos x_{10}.
> $$

Comment: If $x_1 = x_2 = \ldots = x_{10} \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ such that $\sin^2 x_1 = \frac{1}{10} \implies \sin x_1 = \sqrt{\frac{1}{10}}$ and $\cos x_1 = \sqrt{\frac{9}{10}}$, then,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{10} \cos x_i = 3 \left( \sum_{i=1}^{10} \sin x_i \right)$$

If $x_1 = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $x_2 = x_3 = \ldots = x_{10} = 0$ then,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{10} \cos x_i = 9 \geq 3 = 3 \left( \sum_{i=1}^{10} \sin x_i \right)$$

If we deviate from the first case of equal $x_i$'s (when equality is achieved), the RHS tends to become larger and larger than the LHS. I'll try to prove this.

Comment: David, you're not going to learn how to solve contest math questions without trying yourself to do so.  (I'm referring to your initial tag "Olympiad problems = contest math".)  I see no thoughts from you on the question, no effort or attempt from you within your question body.  We're not here to "train you" by giving you answers to questions you'll need to master.

Comment: What have you tried, David?  What is the source of this question? Which Olymiad?

Comment: I apologize if I wasn't clear with my intentions. I spent a good 3 hours working on this problem, writing it in different forms using various identities and trying use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. I was aware of the extremal cases from the beginning (one always should). I've never posted a 'contest problem' before so was unaware of protocol. I'm seriously stumped but do not expect to be handed an answer by any means, just perhaps a tiny nudge. The problem was posed by Alexandru Lupas in 1987 in the American Mathematics Monthly; it was never an olympiad problem but I feel it has that flavour.

Comment: Saint-Petersburg mathematical olympiad, 2001

Comment: Thanks for your comment/response David.  We can't know all that unless you tell us! That comment offers a whole bunch of information which helps answerers to better answer the question.  I appreciate your responsiveness!

Comment: To avoid having your question closed due to lack of context, we recomment you include the context in the question.

Comment: Thanks @amWhy, I'm a bit new (although not to mathematics by any means). I really appreciate your feedback in using this forum - I should definitely have been more clear where I was coming from and what I had tried. I am very thankful for everyone's feedback and ideas!

Comment: @Macavity I don't think that it's duplicate exactly,  because my solution of this problem is different than all other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

First of all notice that $$n\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2 \ge \left( \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \right)^2$$Proof: Notice that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n (y_j - y_i)^2 = (n-1)\left( \sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2 \right) - 2\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^n y_iy_j\right) \ge 0$$It follows that 
$$n\left( \sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2 \right) - 2\left(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^n y_iy_j\right)$$ $$=n\left( \sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2 \right) - \left(\sum_{i=1}^ny_i\right)^2 \ge 0$$ proving the inequality.

Now notice that $$\cos(x_1) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1, i\ne 1}^{10}\sin^2(x_i)},$$ $$ \cos(x_2) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1, i\ne 2}^{10}\sin^2(x_i)}$$ $$...$$. Now observe that $$9\sum_{i=1, i\ne 1}^{10}\sin^2(x_i) \ge \left( \sum_{i=1, i\ne 1}^{10} \sin(x_i) \right)^2$$ from the first inequality, implying that $$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1, i\ne 1}^{10}\sin^2(x_i)} \ge \frac{\left( \sum_{i=1, i\ne 1}^{10} \sin(x_i) \right)}3$$, i.e. $$\cos(x_1) \ge \frac{\left( \sum_{i=1, i\ne 1}^{10} \sin(x_i) \right)}3$$ Similarly $$\cos(x_2) \ge \frac{\left( \sum_{i=1, i\ne 2}^{10} \sin(x_i) \right)}3$$ $$...$$. Adding all these inequalities, we get $$\left(\cos(x_1) + \cos(x_2) + ... + \cos(x_{10})\right) \ge \frac{\left( \sum_{i=1, i\ne 1}^{10} \sin(x_i) \right)}3 + \frac{\left( \sum_{i=1, i\ne 2}^{10} \sin(x_i) \right)}3 + ... + \frac{\left( \sum_{i=1, i\ne 10}^{10} \sin(x_i) \right)}3$$ $$=3\left(\sin(x_1) + \sin(x_2) + ... + \sin(x_{10})\right)$$ proving the inequality.

Answer (score 2):

TL method helps here very well!!!

Let $\sin x_i=\sqrt{\frac{a_i}{10}}$, where $a_i\geq0$.

Hence,  $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}a_i=10$ and we need to prove that $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}\left(\cos x_i-3\sin x_i\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{i=1}^{10}\left(\sqrt{10-a_i}-3\sqrt{a_i}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{i=1}^{10}\left(\frac{1-a_i}{\sqrt{10-a_i}+3\sqrt{a_i}}+\frac{a_i-1}{6}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{i=1}^{10}\frac{(a_i-1)\left(\sqrt{10-a_i}+3\sqrt{a_i}-6\right)}{\sqrt{10-a_i}+3\sqrt{a_i}}\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{i=1}^{10}\frac{(a_i-1)^2\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{a_i}+1}-\frac{1}{3+\sqrt{10-a_i}}\right)}{\sqrt{10-a_i}+3\sqrt{a_i}}\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Done!